# Where should one post questions about computer methods for computational mathematics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've posted a [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32741/obtaining-integer-digits-using-the-gnu-multiprecision-arithmetic-library-gmplib) about the use of the GNU Multiprecision Arithmetic Library (gmplib) on another Stack Exchange site ([Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com)) but I'm not at all sure that it is the correct place. Where should one post a question like the one I asked? And what tags might be appropriate?

Comment: That Q&A doesn't mention [scicomp.se]; perhaps it should be added as [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on#comment914572_129632) and the next one suggest?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're in the [right place](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Computational Science** is a question and answer site for questions and answers about computational methods used in technical disciplines.

When in doubt if a certain site is the correct place, there's a few things you can do:

- Check the article "What topics can I ask about here?" in their [Help Center](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In this case, it's quite extensive.
- Search if there are existing questions using the same technologies as you do. In this case, I must admit the results are rather [pessimistic](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=gmplib)...
- Check their own [Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/) for questions tagged [scope] or (in this case) [[site-scope]](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-scope) for more details about what is in scope or not.

and generally you should do it *before* actually posting the question :)

At Meta Stack Exchange, we don't decide whether a question is on-topic for a certain Stack Exchange site or not; we can merely give some pointers about which site we *think* is the best fit for your question. (Or none, if it doesn't fit at all in the network.)